# How to workaround with kafka for request-response mechanism?

Tags: java, message-queue, esb, apache-kafka

We would like to have Kafka as our Enterprise Service Bus (ESB).

I know that most use-cases with kafka are async cases.

Is it still possible to work around this and have a request-response messaging between two endpoints in our system using kafka?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535785/does-kafka-support-request-response-messaging

Answer (score 2):

I did not do this explicitly in Kafka but the usual way to do this is to register your producer to a random "reply topic", send the request message including this reply topic and make the consumer take this reply topic and send the response there. The requester may block after sending each message waiting for the response.